# What are some commercial apps for Ubuntu?

Tags: paid-applications, commercial

Anything including games and obscure software

Comment: What's the purpose of this question? Are you looking for examples on how to sell commercial software for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, I'm assuming that by "commercial" you mean "for-pay" with no implications regarding Free/Non-Free.

The [Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=19) sells Parallels and PowerDVD.  There are Linux versions of Quake and Doom as well.

Comment: +1 for canonical store. I didn't know about that.

Comment: Linux versions of Doom were never released commercially.  The source code was released after the end-of-life of the commercial product.  In Doom's case, the source was ported to Linux prior to release, and was then released for free.

Answer (score 6):

The [Humble Indie Bundle](http://www.wolfire.com/humble) is a commercial collection of games that was sold as "pay what you want". The games are available for puchase independently now.

Answer (score 6):

there are not some, but **A LOT** of commercial apps for linux, check http://lin-app.com/ :)

Comment: Nice link, but sadly seems dead since 04/2011.

Answer (score 2):

If you do mean "For Purchase" software, there is a section for such applications in the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image: 'For Purchase' Section in Ubuntu Software Center]

Currently, it only contains 'Fluendo DVD Player', which is being sold for US$ 24.95.

[image: Fluendo DVD Player]

Other applications will probably be added in the future. This is still a new feature.

Comment: Apps will be added to the 'For purchase' section of the store in 11.04. Over the coming release cycle, the plan is to test the payment system and to collect app submission from developers for release next April.

Comment: In fact more have been added before 11.04 ;) well one more for now..